# Euler's method approximation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

I'm supposed to write a program for approximating the value of function $y = y(x)$, which is given as: $$y' = \frac{1+y}{1 + x^2}$$  I also know that $y(0) = 0$. I should approximate the value for $x=2$.

Solving the differential equation gets me that $y = Ke^{\arctan(x)} -1$, where $K\in\mathbb{R}^+$
So I can get the value of $K$ by solving $0 = Ke^{\arctan(0)} - 1$. Therefore $K = 1$.

But I'm not sure if the approximation should use the function in the original shape or the result of the differential equation.

If I use $y = e^{\arctan(x)} - 1$ for the aprroximation, the results are ($h$ is the size of step):
For $h=1$ it is $2.0$
For $h=0.5$ it is $2,02885...$
For $h=0.25$ it is $2,03366...$

The precise value is $y(2) = e^{\arctan(2)} - 1 = 2.0257189050$

Code used to calculate the results:

```
DWORD ApproximateExampleOne(){
    double stepSize = 0.0;
    double result = 0.0;
    double iterator = 0.0;
    double preciseValue = exp(atan(2.0)) - 1;

    fflush(stdin);
    _tprintf(_T("Approximating equation [y = e^(arctan(x)) - 1] for x = 2 by Euler's method\n\n"));
    _tprintf(_T("Please enter size of the step [#.#]: "));
    _tscanf(_T("%lf"), &stepSize);

    if(stepSize <= 0){
        _tprintf(_T("Size of the step can't be zero or negative! Aborting... \n"));
        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    for(iterator = stepSize; iterator < 2.0; iterator += stepSize){
        result = result + stepSize*(exp(atan(iterator)) - 1);
    }

    _tprintf(_T("\nPrecise result is: %.10f\n"), preciseValue);
    _tprintf(_T("Approximate result is: %.10f\n"), result);
    _tprintf(_T("Approximation error is: %2.0f%%"), (fabs(preciseValue - result)/fabs(preciseValue))*100);

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You know more about the requirements of your course than we do, but given that you're tagging it (numerical-methods), it's certainly conceivable that you're supposed to solve it numerically rather than symbolically. For example, the point could be that you can then compare your results with the known exact solution.

Comment: I have expanded the question a bit, since your comment is certainly true.

Comment: "the results are" - maybe you might want to include the precise calculations you did for, say, $h=1$; it looks to me you're not doing what you were expected to do.

Comment: I'll paste a snippet of the code here.

Comment: Oh, dear. As I said in my answer, you're not supposed to "know" the exact solution when you're using Euler! The $f(x,y)$ in the formulae I gave should be replaced with whatever $y^\prime$ is equated to!

Comment: @J.M. Can you please tell me whether it is now correct?

Comment: Well, the result I get corresponding to $h=.25$ is $2.034039416603703$... otherwise, your other values look dandy.

Comment: Err - what's the meaning of dandy?

Comment: And looking at it once more I have the same result for $h = 0.25$ as you said just now, I've just copyied a different number. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, when you're using Euler's method, the assumption there is that you're unable or unwilling to find a symbolic solution to your differential equation, and you just want to estimate the function values of a solution at a few points.

Remember that Euler's method for $y^\prime=f(x,y)$ takes the form

$$\begin{align*}x_{k+1}&=x_k+h\\y_{k+1}&=y_k+hf(x_k,y_k)\end{align*}$$

where $h$ is a predetermined stepsize and $x_0,y_0$ correspond to your initial conditions.

That's what you need to do here: pick a stepsize $h$, let $x_0=y_0=0$ (due to your initial conditions), and then keep running Euler (replacing $f(x,y)$ with whatever's equated to the derivative) up until $x_{k+1}=2$. The corresponding value of $y_{k+1}$ is the Euler estimate, which I presume you'll be asked to compare with the exact solution in this case...

Comment: I've had this in mind and I have a solution ready (I've included it in my question), but I'm not totally sure whether I am using the right form for the approximation. So if you coud just please verify it or tell me that I am using a wrong form. That's all I ask :)